# Limit a listview to 25 items

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-listview

I am displaying a listview programmiclly using the following codes:
Below is how the listview is displayed programmatically:

```
 messagesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMessages);
            messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this);
```

I would want to limit the list to 25 items, and where it is not infinite.

Below is the layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/white_wallpaper"
                >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listMessages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/divider"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:padding="0dip"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        tools:listitem="@layout/message_left" />

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="@color/off_white"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relSendMessage" />

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relSendMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="#ddd"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/messageBodyField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sendButton"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sendButton"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sendButton"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:hint="@string/message_elipses"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorLink="#adefda"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/sendButton"
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_send" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/iSchedule"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:background="#C11B17"
        android:text="Schedule"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have been suggested the following, but I am not sure how to integrate it within the above code:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 25;
}
```

Thanks in advance, and for any clarification, let me know.

**Update**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.messaging);

        feedBack = new FeedbackDialog(this, "ID");



        final TextView iSchedule = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.iSchedule);
        iSchedule.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               MessagingActivity1.this.startActivity(new Intent(MessagingActivity1.this, ScheduleMatchOptionActivity.class));
            }
        });

        Parse.initialize(this, "ID", "ID");

        bindService(new Intent(this, MessageService.class), serviceConnection,
                BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        recipientId = intent.getStringExtra("RECIPIENT_ID");
        currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
        messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this);

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
    messagesList.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
            return 25;
        }

        messagesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMessages);


        populateMessageHistory();
        messageBodyField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageBodyField);
        findViewById(R.id.sendButton).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        sendMessage();
                    }
                });
    }
```

However, I receive the following error 
in the live @override it says Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
in the public int get count "Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)"
In the return 25 - Void methods cannot return a value

Answer (score 3):

You want to use that code (or similar) to override the default `getCount` method in ListAdapter: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html

You can check an example in: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#listview_listviewexample

Comment: thanks for your prompt response. So would it be something more like this?  @Override
    public int getCount() {
messagesList.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
        return 25;
    }

Comment: Yep <br>
But take into account that with that code you will always get 25 elements in the list. You will need to use something like: `if(super.getCount()>25) return 25 else return super.getCount()`

Comment: I guess that could work since I want up to 25 in a list, and it doesn't neccearly have to be 25, just thats the maximum number

Comment: Thanks. I have added an update section under my initial post. It highlights many of the problems I haveThanks

Comment: Nono. You have to override it in your custom MessageAdapter class. In you updated example, you are trying to override a method inside an onCreate method; if that code correspond to MessageAdapter, the getCount part has to be at the same level as onCreate.

Comment: how would i create a custom adapter?

Comment: Seems like you are missing some basic Android building blocks. You should really go through the official Android Getting Started tutorial (it'll take about 15 hours): http://developer.android.com/training/index.html About the custom-adapter, as simple as searching "android custom list adapter": http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#tutorial_ownadapter

Answer (score 1):

Hey you want to get list with limit, you have two option
1. You set array list size,
2. You can set, when you get data put for loop and set limit

Comment: Thank you. I would prefer option 1, how would that work?

Comment: where from you get data, just get first 0 to 24 item not all so you automatically get 25 items in your listview,  like simply for(i = 0 ;i >= 24 ,i++);