# Limit Item in ListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have an ArrayList that contains an X number of items. In my Custom ListView adapter, I have set the getItemCount() to only return 100 items. When I run my app, the listview is rendered, however, when I scroll pass an item at index 75, it gives me an error like so

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 75, Size: 75

I assume that this happens because the ArrayList only has 75 items. I can't return list.size() because the size is always changing, it could be more or less than 100, but I only need to show <= 100 items.

Can someone advice me on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit a listview to 25 items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318120/limit-a-listview-to-25-items)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this as `getCount()`

```
@Override
public int getCount(){
    return items.length() < 100 ? items.length() : 100;
}
```

Because you've set the `getCount()` to `return` 100 explicitly, now if there are not 100 items in that `ArrayList`, it will raise `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, because system will try to fetch 100 items from that `List` which doesn't have that.

So, instead of returning 100 always, return 100 only when there are more than 100 items in that `List`.